# How to duplicate Magento product and add a new SKU with only one "save" action

Tags: magento

I want to duplicate a product and give it successively a new sku in an only one save action.

How can I do that ??

I have tried this code:

```
$sku = '123456';
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
   ->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku); 

$newProduct = $product->duplicate();
$newProduct->setStatus(1);
$newProduct->setSku($sku.'-v2');
$newProduct->save();
```

but it throws this exception:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '3569-1' for key 'IDX_STOCK_PRODUCT'
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5):

```
$newProduct->save();
```

should actually be:

```
$newProduct->getResource()->save($newProduct);
```

Comment: I know it's too late to answer this... but it may help somebody.
Add $newProduct->setData('media_gallery', array()); before $newProduct->getResource()->save($newProduct);
In this case images won't duplicate.

Comment: @Konstantin thanks for this comment... You have no idea how long I have spent today trying to figure this one out!